So I have managed to send a total of 800$ to a BTC address I used back in 2021
Don't ask how... Nevertheless I didn't know if it was possible to recover the keys from this said address? I still have the address and can tell all the transactions to and from it...
I have tried using a key scanner and after countless hours no luck... So essentially 800$ is just sitting in Neverland.


I didn't know if it was possible to recover the keys from this said address?

Private keys cannot be obtained from Bitcoin addresses. If this were not so, anyone could spend anyone else's money.
